# Match URL path and children

Tags: regex

I'm looking to match a sub directory and its children with regex. I have little knowledge of Regex and I am currently learning, so please don't see my lack of example as laziness.

For example, if someone enters blog, it would match

```
blog
blog/foobar
blog/foo-bar
blog/foo/bar
```

But not match

```
blog-foo
blogger
foo/blog
foo/blog/bar
```

There is no limit to the depth of the children.

Thanks in advance

Comment: blog-foo is not a subdirectory...Can you please tell us what exactly should be matched ? do we need to exactly match blog/ and then all subdirectories inside blog/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This should do the trick

```
^blog(?:\/.*|)$
```

Test it [here](https://regex101.com/r/Pe2oDp/1).

Comment: @jhine that will also allow `blog/` and `blog/../../..` and `blog/////` - cases you haven't defined.

Comment: @AmigoJack - Any non alpha-numeric is fine, but thank you very much for informing me :)